# Диалоги в Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, dialog

Подскажите как именно сделать диалог в Unity.
Что бы например при нажатии на нпс мышкой, рядом появлялось сообщение,
с возможностью нажать кнопку "Далее"

Comment: 1. реализовать нажатие кнопкой мыши на нпс. 2. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы ловить нажатие на NPC используйте [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

```cs
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
{

}
```

Он выпускает луч в определённую сторону и возвращает список объектов которые столкнулись с этим лучом. После этого проверяйте есть ли данный NPC в списке и активируйте раннее приготовленный диалог вот так -

```cs
dialogPanel.SetActive(true);
```